# how to manipulate elements in the priority queue in boost C++

Tags: c++, boost

I have a problem to deal with the pairing priority queues in boost C++. I have an item array {0,1,2,3,...}, and each item has a priority value. These priority queues construct another array {key0 for item 0, key1 for item 1, ...}.

In the algorithm, I need to select several items to put them in a priority queue. For example, I may select item 1, 2, 3 into a queue, ordered by their priority values (keys). Then, I need to remove a specific item. For example, I may want to remove item 2 from the queue of item 1, 2, 3, and item 2 may NOT have the maximal/minimal priority values.

Below is a queue I created using the pairing queue in boost.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/heap/pairing_heap.hpp>
pairing_heap<float> pq;

pq.push(1);
pq.push(2.5);
auto handle = pq.push(3.1);
pq.erase(handle); // remove an element by handle
cout << "pq top=" << pq.top() << endl; // a const_reference to the maximum element.
```

You can see that I can only push the priority values into the queue, and if I want to remove an item, I need to know its handle value. However, I don't know how to give handle values to a large amount of items. Hope there is someone who knows how to do it. Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe the question is not clear enough. In my case, each item in the queue has two values, the first value is int, such as 1, 2, 3, while the second value is the priority value (float). I want to update the priority of an item with the known first value, like (int) 1, but I don't know its current priority value or location in the queue. In conclusion, I need to manipulate an item by its first int value, not by its priority values or locations in the queue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `s_handle_from_iterator`

```
pq.update(Heap::s_handle_from_iterator(pq.begin()), pq.top()*2);
std::cout << "pq top=" << pq.top() << std::endl;
```

Prints "5".

It took a bit of digging, but I found the [docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/doc/html/boost/heap/d_ary_heap.html#idm46563410073984-bb) stating the **operation is constant-time** (documentation refers to `d_ary_heap` in the source).

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1f0b0ef0bb9b7faa)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/heap/pairing_heap.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    using Heap = boost::heap::pairing_heap<float>;
    Heap pq;

    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(2.5);
    auto handle = pq.push(3.1);
    pq.erase(handle); // remove an element by handle
    std::cout << "pq top=" << pq.top() << std::endl; // a const_reference to the maximum element.

    pq.update(Heap::s_handle_from_iterator(pq.begin()), pq.top()*2);
    std::cout << "pq top=" << pq.top() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Many thanks! I understand that your code is trying to update the priority of the top value. However, in my case, each item in the queue has two values, the first value is int, such as 1, 2, 3, while the second value is the priority value (float). I want to update the priority of an item with the known first value, like (int) 1, but I don't know its current priority value or location in the queue. So, I'm not sure if s_handle_from_iterator works in this case? In conclusion, I need to manipulate an item by its first int value, not by its priority values or locations in the queue. Many thanks!

Comment: You understand that queues are not intended for random access, right. Can't you just mark the element with a deleted flag and then when the consumer dequeues it test for that? `if (!item.is_deleted()) { /*...*/ };`